# Should I add my newborn (born to UK partner in UK) as a dependent on my visa application

Tags: uk-visa, children

I'm applying for a partner visa (to my British citizen husband)

I had started my application while pregnant so didn't declare the child as he didn't have a birth date. Now he is born, I've put on the application as a dependent but is it right that he should be declared as such and pay another visa fee for him?

On the form, there was another section called "non applying children". This section is now locked for this application so I can't go back and change it. If this is where my baby should be declared I'll have to redo all of my application hence why I'm asking here first.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check if your information is correct, but if your partner and child’s father is a UK citizen, then your child is UK citizen. If the child was born in the UK, then he or she is British citizen “not by descent”, which is even better.

In that case your child cannot get a UK visa - the one group of people who can’t get a UK visa at all are UK citizens. But a visa is not needed, because the child can enter the Uk without a visa as a UK citizen.

Comment: I which case, the child would need a British passport https://www.gov.uk/uk-border-control/before-you-leave-for-the-uk